# convert Chinese ascii string to Chinese language string

Tags: python, encoding, ascii, windows-10

I tried to use `sys` module to set default encoding to convert the string, but it does not work.

**The string is:**

```
`\xd2\xe6\xc3\xf1\xba\xcb\xd0\xc4\xd4\xf6\xb3\xa4\xbb\xec\xba\xcf`
```

it means `益民核心增长混合` in Chinese. But How can I convert this to Chinese language string?

**I tried this:**

```
>>> string = '\xd2\xe6\xc3\xf1\xba\xcb\xd0\xc4\xd4\xf6\xb3\xa4\xbb\xec\xba\xcf'
>>> print string.decode("gbk")
益民核心增长混合  # As you can see here, got the right answer
>>> new_str = string.decode("gbk")
>>> new_str
u'\u76ca\u6c11\u6838\u5fc3\u589e\u957f\u6df7\u5408' # It returns the another encode type.
>>> another = u"益民核心增长混合"
>>> another
u'\u76ca\u6c11\u6838\u5fc3\u589e\u957f\u6df7\u5408' # same as new_str
```

So, I just confused by this situation, why I can print `string.decode("gbk")` but the `new_str` in my python console just return another encode type?

My OS is Windows 10, my Python version is Python 2.7. Thank you very much!

Comment: have same problem

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly.

In this case, `new_str` is actually a *unicode* string as denoted by the `u` prefix.

```
>>> new_str
u'\u76ca\u6c11\u6838\u5fc3\u589e\u957f\u6df7\u5408' # It returns the another encode type.
```

When you decode the GBK encoded string, you get a unicode string. Each character of this string is a unicode code point, e.g.

```
>>> u'\u76ca'
u'\u76ca'
>>> print u'\u76ca'
益
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u76ca')
'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-76CA'

>>> print new_str
益民核心增长混合
>>> print repr(new_str)
u'\u76ca\u6c11\u6838\u5fc3\u589e\u957f\u6df7\u5408
```

This is how Python displays unicode strings in the interpreter - it is using `repr` to display it. But when you print the string, Python converts to the encoding for your terminal (`sys.stdout.encoding`), and that's why the string is displayed as you expect.

So, it's not a different encoding of the string, it's just the way that Python displays the string in the interpreter.